# Unpaid Leave in non-US Company on F-1 Visa

Tags: usa, student-visa

When in the US on an F-1 visa, is it permissible to be on unpaid leave in a non-US company? As far as I know, working for a non-US company is not permissible on an F-1 visa, but in this case no work would be done nor compensation received. Thanks.